# How to determine if my model is robust? Should the coefficients be same?

Tags: logistic, least-squares, regression-coefficients, post-hoc, robust

I want to run robustness tests for my model. For example, by reducing the sample to heavily concentrated groups, running a different regression (probit etc) etc. But, how do I ascertain that my results are robust? Is it sufficient that my key explanatory variables have same sign as the original model, magnitude of coefficients is similar and that they are significant? Is it necessary that the coefficients are exactly same?

Thank you

Comment: You may look at the standard errors, if they are big...

Comment: It’s not an easy question, +1. one way could be to fit the model by some robust estimators and compare the differences, if any.

Comment: You seem to use "robust" in a general sense. Thinking about robustness in a broadly defined sense might not be the most fruitful direction. It may be better to decide what quantities you want to estimate/compare and then estimate those robustly. For example, perhaps you are studying different groups (eg males vs females) and you want to compare those group in terms of a robust measure of central tendency. Or alternatively you might do model validation to ascertain that your model fits the data well. This second option seems to be what the question points towards.